# I am getting an error "No signature of method"

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, mobile-development

I am getting the following error, and I see a lot of people refer to changing androidResources to aaptOptions, so I am wondering where would androidResources be located within the app structure?

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> No signature of method: build_7ti7vojh4f95jk83rqtiw9b5b.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_7ti7vojh4f95jk83rqtiw9b5b$_run_closure1) values: [build_7ti7vojh4f95jk83rqtiw9b5b$_run_closure1@611ff2ec]

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.